# Gmail to Google Sheets - put mail into spreadsheet and remove html from body

Tags: html, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I am trying to use the code below but I get an error when trying to run it. It is supposed to look for gmail with a set label, then put the email body (have stripped the HTML) into a google sheet.

```
var SEARCH_QUERY = "label:inbox is:unread to:me";

// Credit: https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/70e04a67f1f5fd96a708

function getEmails_(q) {
var emails = [];
var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
for (var i in threads) {
    var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j in msgs) {
        emails.push([msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g, '\n')
            .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n')
        ]);
    }
}
return emails;
}

function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}

function saveEmails() {
var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
if (array2d) {
    appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), array2d);
}
}
```

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 20, file "test")

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try to debug your script yourself (look what is the the value of array2D) See [troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the code below to do what I was originally trying to do so I thought I would share this so as others can achieve what I was trying to do. All you need to do is insert the gmail email label to search for. I didn't want to put the email subject into the spreadsheet so I removed this from the ss.appendRow([dat,msg]) line. Just add it back in if you need this. 
Thanks to everyone for the assistance.

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("GMAIL EMAIL LABEL NAME HERE");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
{
  var msg = messages[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g, '\n').replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n');
  var sub = messages[j].getSubject();
  var dat = messages[j].getDate();

  ss.appendRow([dat, msg])
}
  threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance `array2d` does not seem like a 2d array but a simple array, which would throw because of `array2d[0].length`. Your `getEmails_()` seems to just return an array of strings as you simply push the body to `emails` array